# Convertir lo que hay en el main en una funcion general

Tags: c, programacion-asincrona

He creado un codigo el cual consite en lo siguinete:

El codigo lo que hace es leer un archivo .txt y lo guarda en un arreglo; el parametro que le paso a la funcion fopen es un string. el cual quiero que sea una parametro en la funcion llamado nombre_archivo y quiero que el nombre del arreglo donde se almacenen los datos del archivo .txt se llame de cierta manera por lo que tambien debe ser un parametro, llamado nombre_arreglo, para pasarlo en la funcion.

En el codigo el archivo que lee se llama animales.txt y lo almacena en un arreglo llamado animales.

pero no se muy bien como converti este codigo a una funcion para solo llamarla en la fucnion main con los parametros (nombre_archivo , nombre_arreglo).

Me podrian ayudar por favor, este es el codigo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>


int main ()
{
    //******* Aqui comineza la lectura del archivo animales ****************

        int n = 0; // *Contador para el numero de lineas
        char str[20] = "animales.txt";

        FILE *fp = fopen(str,"r");
        if(fp == NULL)
        {
            printf("Error al abrir el archivo, puede que no exista!");
            return 1;
        } 

        // *Permite contar el numero de lineas que contiene cada categoria de juego.
        // ************* Animales ************************
        char tamanio_archivo[50];
        while (!feof(fp))
        {
            fscanf(fp,"%s", tamanio_archivo);
            n++;  
        }

        rewind(fp);  // *Funciona para rebobinar el puntero al inio del archivo

        char animales[n][50];
        int a=0;
        while (!feof(fp))
        {
            fscanf(fp,"%s",animales[a]);
            a++;
        }

        //****** Imprime el arreglo ****************************
        for (a = 0; a< n; a++)\
        {
            printf("%s \n",animales[a]);
        }

        fclose(fp);
     //***** Termina la lectura del archivo *****************

    //**** Aqui se inicia elegir una palabra al azar *********
    int opcion;

    srand(time(NULL));
    
    opcion = rand() % 10; //SE GENERA UN NUMERO ALEATORIO COMPRENDIDO ENTRE 0 Y 9 para elegir una de las palabras para adivinar
    printf("\n El numero de la palabra selccionada es: %i ",opcion);

    printf("\n La palabra en la posicion %i es: %s ",opcion,animales[opcion] );
    
    return 0;
}
```

Intente realizarlo pero me dan varios errores, he intentado realizarlo de muchos maneras pero no lo consegui.

Comment: el codigo se sube como texto no como imagenes, lee [ask].

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque las imágenes no son código.

Comment: Bienvenido. ¿Cuáles son los intentos que hiciste? Lo que quieres hacer no es tan complicado. Deberías poder acercarte a la solución para que le demos el golpe que le falta y aprendas.

Comment: nombre_arreglo, que seria, una cadena(si es así complicado)? Creo que deberías usar memoria dinámica.Entiendo que quieres reutilizar la función para varios archivos y/o personajes del juego.

Answer (score 0):

Una solución para no usar memoria dinámica(malloc) y poder reutilizar el código seria partir en dos subrrutinas, la lectura del archivo:

```
int tamano_archivo(char * nombre_archivo);
int cargar_archivo(char * nombre_archivo, char nombre_arrego[][50],int n);
int main ()
{
int n;

n=tamano_archivo("sopa.txt");
char sopa[n][50];
n=cargar_archivo("sopa.txt",sopa,n);

//**** Aqui se inicia elegir una palabra al azar *********

n=tamano_archivo("animales.txt");
char animales[n][50];
n=cargar_archivo("animales.txt",animales,n);

//**** Aqui se inicia elegir una palabra al azar *********

}
```

Solo faltaría implementar las dos funciones con el código que ya esta hecho.